# Swift animate view in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

For an app that I'm developing, I'm using a tableview. My tableview, has of course a tableviewcell. In that tableviewcell I'm adding a view programmatically (so nothing in storyboard). It's a view where I draw some lines and text and that becomes a messagebubble. If the messagebubble is seen by the other user you sent it too , a line of the bubble will go open.

So I have the animation function inside the class of that UIView (sendbubble.swift)

Now, it already checks if it is read or not and it opens the right bubble. But normally it should animate (the line that goes open should rotate) in 0.6 seconds. But it animates instantly. So my question is, how do I animate it with a duration?

I would also prefer to still call it in my custom UIView class (sendbubble.swift) . Maybe I need code in my function to check if the cell is presented on my iphone?

Thanks in advance!

```
func openMessage() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        var t = CATransform3DIdentity;
        t = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(3 * Float.pi / 4), 0, 0, 1)
        self.moveableLineLayer.transform = t;
    }, completion:{(finished:Bool) in })
}
```

Comment: write self.view.layoutifneeded() into uiview.animate

Comment: @JeckyModi it says "value of type sendbubble has no member view" but sendbubble is an UIView class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UITableViewDelegate method `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

That is triggered when the cell is about to be drawn - not when it is created.  You will also need to store a state in your model that says if the animation has occurred, otherwise it will happen every time the cell comes back into view.

**EXAMPLE**

In the view controller (pseudo code)

```
class CustomViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    //where ever you define your tableview
    var tableView:UITableView
    tableView.delegate = self

    var dataSource //some array that is defining your cells - each object has a property call hasAnimated

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: ITableViewCell, 
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? CustomTableViewCell, dataSource[indexPath.row].hasAnimated == false {
            dataSource[indexPath.row].hasAnimated = true
            cell.openMessage()
        }
    }
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    func openMessage() { //your method
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't call that method in my UIView class? I've added the UITableViewDelegate and I did add this method but it doesn't get called.

Comment: Can you share the code you used to add the delegate and call the method.  You can definitely call the method in the UIView class, assuming its referenced by the TableViewCell - which you can get using the indexPath.

Comment: class sendBubble: UIView, UITableViewDelegate {}

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("this doesn't print")
        if (messageSeen == "last seen") {
            openMessage()
        }
    }

Comment: See my edit - you have to set an object as your UITableViewDelegate - this should not be your cells, as there is _only 1_ delegate at a time.  This is why the delegate methods have a way to reference the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the openMessage method is not in the UITableViewCell class, it is in a UIView class named 'sendbubble' like I said in my question. Hope you can help me out with this

Comment: @MaximVW what is the relation of SendBubble to the view containing the tableview or the cells?  Does every cell have an instance of SendBubble?  Or a single SendBubble at the level of the view which holds the tableview?

Comment: I figured out how to call the openmessage method for a specific cell. But now I only call this method when I press a button (I used a button to test if my code works) but I need to run this code when the cell is loaded. the func  with tableview will display is called before my cell is loaded and I can't find a method for after it's loaded, do you have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some more code so I can understand what class openMessage is a method of, and how it relates to your tableview and tableviewcells?

Comment: It's just a view with some uibezierpath lines. It's in an other .swift file than my cell file , in my cell file (class) that view is created, a new view of this gets called and placed in the cell (addsubview..) nothing more. The only thing I need is a method in my ViewController class that gets called after the cell is loaded with the view already in it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to grab the cell.

1. Get the indexPath of that cell where you need to show open bubble.
2. Get the cell from `tableView.cellForRowAt(at:indexPath)`
3. We will now have access to that bubble view now you can animate using the same function `func openMessage()`

Any question? comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! where do you want me to get the indexpath? in the class of my VC where the tableview is? or the class of the cell? or the class of my sendbubble?

Comment: Inside VC where your tableView is. There must be some web service call where you determine that message is sent, from there find the index of the message object in that array which you are populating in tableView. The index will be same for cell as well. Use that index to get the cell.

Comment: I am able to get the index and so, but it still doesn't animate, the animation is already done. So I would need to call this after the cell is fully loaded. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you need to animate on loaded cell (visible cells). I have not tested your animation method though but try with some normal animation method it should definitely work.